# calculate the x-axis average bar

Tags: matlab

I have a simple problem.

I have this code:

```
test = [30,40,60,30,20,10,5,5,3]
bar(test)
```

The bar represent the child number by family. For example, 30 family have 0 child and 10 family have 5 children.

I want to obtain the child average by family and of course I can't just use mean(test).

Comment: Try writing out the equation you would use to solve this problem by hand and I think you can figure out how to implement it in Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can easily convert your data in a form where each entry of a vector represents an observation of a family with a value for the number of children. This way we generate a vector with length of the total number of families. Each entry is a number representing the amount of children of the observed family.

To do this we can use [`arrayfun`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and [`repmat`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to repeat the entries in `cnt` as many times as there are corresponding families in `test`. Since the output of `arrayfun` is a cell-array, we need to use [`cell2mat`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to convert it back to a 'normal' matrix. After that, `obs` is the above mentioned vector. Now we can simply use `mean` or `var` to calculate what you need.

*Here is an example:*

```
test = [30,40,60,30,20,10, 5 ,5, 3] % families
cnt  = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] % children per family in test

obs = arrayfun(@(s,c)repmat(c,1,s),test,cnt,'UniformOutput',false);
obs = cell2mat(obs);

mean(obs)                           % mean
var(obs)                            % variance
```

*This is the result:*

```
ans =
    2.3103
ans =
    3.2349
```

*Note: I assume that there are 30 families with 0 children (as your text says) and not 30 families with one child (as your bar-plot says). Just adjust `cnt` to match your needs.*

---

To get `test` and `cnt` back from `obs`, you can use `hist` like this:

```
[test,cnt] = hist(obs,unique(obs));
```

---

For the creation of your bar-plot, use `bar` with two arguments. This way you have the correct x-values (in this case `cnt`).

```
bar(cnt,test)

xlabel('Children per family')
ylabel('Number of Families')
```

[image: example_barplot]

Comment: So i can't use mean. I need to rewrite mean. And if I want the variance?

Comment: @sushi: I edited my answer completely to use a different method and provided some additional information.